# JS scrollIntoView function on mousewheel isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the script above, which is outputing the right id on the browser console, but not scrolling:

```
var divID = null;
var up = null;
var down = null;

function div(x) {
    switch(x.id) {
        case 's1':
            up = null;
            down = 's2';
            break;
        case 's2':
            up = 's1';
            down = 's3'
            break;
        case 's3':
            up = 's2';
            down ='s4';
            break;
        case 's4':
            up = 's3';
            down = null;
            break;
        default:
            up = null;
            down = null;
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {          
    if (e.deltaY < 0 && up) {
        console.log(up);
        document.getElementById(up).scrollIntoView();
    }
    if (e.deltaY > 0 && down) {
        console.log(down);
        document.getElementById(down).scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```

And i'm using this structure:

```
<div id='s1' onmouseover="div(this)">
    <!--content-->
</div>
<div id='s2' onmouseover="div(this)">
    <!--content-->
</div>
<div id='s3' onmouseover="div(this)">
    <!--content-->
</div>
<div id='s4' onmouseover="div(this)">
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

As I said, the console.log prints what it should, but scrolling does nothing, just regular scroll.
I'm using wordpress if it matters.

Comment: You're using the `wheel` event, which will only be triggered when a physical wheel (or trackpad scrolling) is used. Check out [the `scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll).

Comment: Let us assume that he/she is using a mouse to test, since it is sort of expected. There is no way to re-create this because it actually works. Check other reasons why it does not behave as you expect it to, this particular code works.

Comment: @ShengSlogar As I said, the console.log() line inside the wheel event is working fine and showing the right ID's on browser console. So it is triggering, isn't it?

Comment: Try adding an e.preventDefault() into the scroll event.

Comment: @bronkula Thanks, it worked!!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that in certain browsers and operating systems, scrolling into an element will not activate the hover state of that element. Also, if someone dragged the scrollbar, it would not ever activate your hovers.

The hovers here are telling your scroll event where to go, but they require hover actions to be effective. You would do better to find the correct elements with their offsetTop values, rather then require a second event during the scroll.

[edit] Or the scrolling of the scroll event is overriding the potential of the scrollIntoView method. Since, it seems you only want to do a scrolljacked movement, try adding an `e.preventDefault()` into the scroll event.

Comment: e.preventDefault() starting my mousewheel/wheel handler saves me ! Thx